# this function in android seems not working, can anybody give me a explaination?

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public long getDoneLength(int mixId, long startPos) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    long doneLength = 0;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select doneLength from fragment where mixId=? and startPos=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(mixId), String.valueOf(startPos)});
    while (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        doneLength = cursor.getLong(0);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return doneLength;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is this method supposed to do?

Comment: Errors? Does it not return the correct value? I'm also pretty sure you want to be checking the whether the cursor is Null or it's count is 0 before calling moveToFirst().

Comment: Post a stacktrace or something that explains what happens when you say it 'doesn't work.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an infinite loop. You should do `if (cursor.moveToNext()) {...}`, not `while`.

Answer (score 0):

cursor.moveToFirst should only be called once. If you wanna know if the cursor is empty use

```
cursor.isAfterLast()
```

Regards,
 Stéphane